# JFrame pack() and requestFocus() is not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, preferredsize

My main issue is with the following piece of code when setting up a `JFrame`:

1. Why the panel doesn't show if I use the `pack()` and how to make it work?
2. Why the first `requestFocusInWindow()` doesn't work and what the principle to use it?
3. Why the default layout manager of `JPanel` doesn't work if I delete the `setLayout()`?

---

```
public class SoundGUI extends KeyAdapter{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SoundGUI sGUI = new SoundGUI();
    sGUI.setUp();
}
public void setUp () {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Key test");
    frame.setSize (1000, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible (true);

    Panel p = new Panel ();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//why this sentence is necessary  FlowLayout doesn't fill the container but rather lets components size to their preferredSizes.
    p.addKeyListener (this);
    p.requestFocusInWindow();//it's useless here
    //requestFocus only works on focusable components that are displayed.
    MyDrawPanel dp = new MyDrawPanel();
    dp.setBackground(Color.darkGray);

    JLabel test = new JLabel("a trial");
    JButton t = new JButton("b");
    dp.add(t);
    dp.add (test);
    p.add (dp);     
    frame.getContentPane().add(p);
    p.requestFocusInWindow();
    //frame.pack();//why it doesn't work
    //frame.setVisible(true);
}
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel { 
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 42) {
            g2.fill3DRect(i,100 ,20 ,80 ,true);
        }
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        for (int i = 21; i < 1000; i += 42) {
            g2.fill3DRect(i,100 ,20 ,80 ,true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why should `requestFocus` work when you've not actually added the panel to anything that is actually displayed on the screen and available to to the user...or do you just dislike your users ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Call `setVisible(true)` ***after*** calling `pack()`. Makes sense, doesn't it?
- The BorderLayout will tell the MyDrawPanel to fill the p container, since the component is being added in a default way (meaning BorderLayout.CENTER), and that's how BorderLayout works.
- FlowLayout doesn't fill the container but rather lets components size to their preferredSizes.
- Don't mix Swing with AWT components. i.e., don't use Panels, but rather use JPanels.
- requestFocus only works on focusable components that are displayed.
- Better to use Key Bindings than KeyListeners.
- Better to avoid setting the sizes of anything if possible.

---

Based on your new code, your problem is due to you're calling `setSize()`. Most layout managers don't respect this but rather the preferred size. If your drawing JPanel needs to be so big, then make it so. For example try:

```
class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
  private static final int PREF_W = 1000;
  private static final int PREF_H = 300;

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     super.paintComponent(g); //!!   ******** don't forget this!!! *********
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2.setColor(Color.white);
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 42) {
        g2.fill3DRect(i, 100, 20, 80, true);
     }
     g2.setColor(Color.black);
     for (int i = 21; i < 1000; i += 42) {
        g2.fill3DRect(i, 100, 20, 80, true);
     }
  }

  // the getPReferredSize will make this JPanel preferentially be this size
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
  }
}
```

---

Also note that request focus ***does*** work if the component is focusable:

```
  JPanel p = new JPanel(); //!! This should be a JPanel, not a Panel
  p.setFocusable(true); //!! This is needed
  p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  p.addKeyListener(this);
  p.requestFocusInWindow();
```

But also note that KeyListeners should be avoided. Use Key Bindings instead.

Comment: And use light not heavy weight components

Comment: An extension on that note: Swing components usually start with a J.

Comment: Thought you'd get around to it eventually ;)

Comment: thank you. but set which componest visible? it seems that pack still doesn't work

Comment: @user2870532: you might have to create and post a [minimal, compilable and runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to fully understand your problem.

Comment: @user2870532: thanks for getting back to us. Good luck with your coding!